# Displaying altered mysql table contents in JTable in java using Vector

Tags: mysql, vector, jtable, jframe

I have a mysql table that stores the log of Wireless sensor simulation results. It stores node id of each sensor node, energy of each node and and status of each sensor i.e, whether it is in sending state or recieving state etc. Now I want to create  a JTable which displays 5 fileds for each row which are:
NodeId , energy Left, No. Of Packets Sent , No. Of Packets Recieved, No. Of Packets Corrupted.

I am using following queries:

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM node WHERE nodeid='i' AND stetus='sending'

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM node WHERE nodeid='i' AND stetus='corrupted'

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM node WHERE nodeid='i' AND stetus='recieved'

SELECT MIN(energi)  FROM node WHERE nodeid='i'

To get Fields for JTable contents. 
Below is the Code That I have written:  Please help me to resolve this.

I am not able to display JTable.

```
import java.util.Vector.*;
import java.sql.*;
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setSize(800,800);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

         Connection Db=null;
         ResultSet Results,res,rest,re;
         String stetus;
         Vector data = new Vector();
         Vector row = new Vector(50);
         JPanel p = new JPanel();
           Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();
            double energi,nodeid,en;

            String url= "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/prowler";
            String username="root";
            String password = "not telling you";


                   try {
                           Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                           Db= DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password); 
                   }
                     catch(ClassNotFoundException cnf) {
                            System.err.println("Unable to load JDBC bridge" + cnf);   
                            System.exit(1);
                       }

                      catch(SQLException se) {
                               System.err.println("Cannot connect to database" + se);
                               System.exit(2);

                      }

                     int num = Integer.parseInt(name.getSelectedText());   


                        for(int i=1;i<=num;i++)  {

                            row.addElement(i);

                             try {
                     Statement st = Db.createStatement();
                      Results = st.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM node WHERE nodeid='i' AND stetus='sending'");

                   row.addElement(Results.getObject(1));

                             }
                     catch(SQLException se) {
                         System.out.println("Query Not Executed" + se);
                      }


                            try {
                     Statement st = Db.createStatement();
                      res = st.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM node WHERE nodeid='i' AND stetus='corrupted'");
                      row.addElement(res.getObject(1));

                      }
                     catch(SQLException se) {
                         System.out.println("Query Not Executed" + se);
                      }

                             try {
                     Statement st = Db.createStatement();
                      rest = st.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM node WHERE nodeid='i' AND stetus='recieved'");


                       row.addElement(rest.getObject(1));
                            }
                     catch(SQLException se) {
                         System.out.println("Query Not Executed" + se);
                      }

                                    try {
                     Statement st = Db.createStatement();
                      re = st.executeQuery("SELECT MIN(energi)  FROM node WHERE nodeid='i'");

                      row.addElement(re.getObject(1));
                            }
                     catch(SQLException se) {
                         System.out.println("Query Not Executed" + se);
                      }


                  data.addElement(row);


                        }                                           

                  columnNames.add("Node Id");
                  columnNames.add("Packets Sent");
                  columnNames.add("Packets Corrupted");
                  columnNames.add("Packets Recieved");
                  columnNames.add("Energy Left");



   JTable table = new JTable(data,columnNames);
JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(table);
p.add(jsp);
f.add(p);
```

[image: Table NODE schema]

Comment: I've edited out your root password! Course could be too late, suggest you change it.

Comment: k. thanks. But whats the solution?

Comment: Tobe honest not even sure what your question is. If you want the sql you produce the desired result, then we need the table schema.

Comment: You need to learn things like GROUP BY. You could get all this data in a single SQL query.

Comment: @Tony Hopkinson  Can u send me the integrated query please?

Comment: @BabannaDuggani you have to do that work yourself. We aren't going to just give you the code.

Comment: If your SQL is working, try moving the `setVisible()` to the end.

Answer (score 0):

Well if I get you it's fairly simple, something like

```
Select nodeid, 
Count(case stetus when 'sending' then 1 else null end) as Sent,
Count(case stetus when 'received' then 1 else null end) as Received,
Count(case stetus when 'corrupted' then 1 else null end) as Corrupted,
Min(energi) as remaining
From Node Group By NodeId
```

I think

The case manouver inside count is a sneaky trick. Count(SomeColumnName) will skip nulls, but you can count an expression, so you bash one together, that's null when you don't want it in the count.

Comment: Ps if there's a lot of these, you should consider making stetus an integer (have a look up table to gte a nice "english" description), and putting an index on it. You can put an index on VarChar(50) but it's not gong to be anywhere near as quick as one on int.